# I need an EU-located email provider with a good API - any suggestions?

Tags: email, rackspace-cloud

I have a web application that provides an email box for each of our customers. Once we acquire a new customer, we automatically create a mailbox for him. Currently we use Rackspace for that, and it has served us well. I like their REST API.

However, we have to stop using Rackspace since it stores the emails in the US. We have legal constraints that force us to store the emails within the EU.

What alternative for Rackspace would you suggest? The requirements are: a good API and location within EU.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SES. Has servers located in the EU.

[You can also look here](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis)

Comment: Unfortunately AWS SES does not support mailbox provisioning, so its insufficient for my needs.

Comment: Keep in mind that even though Amazon can store your e-mails in the EU, they're an American company that is subject to the Patriot Act. They may or may not have to surrender your data to the US government if they ever ask. If this is an issue for you, you might want to look into alternatives.